# How can I add "Stackdriver Provisioning Service Private" to GCP APIs & Services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

In the GCP APIs & Services Dashboard, "Stackdriver Provisioning Service Private" is displayed. How can I add this API?

[image: "Stackdriver Provisioning Service Private"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff1GO.png)

I want to know how this API is added. Because I accidentally erased this setting because I want to restore it. It seems that I can not add the "Private" API from the "ENABLE APIS AND SERVICES" button. Because it could not be found.

When I place the cursor on "?", It is displayed as "You've been granted access to this service.".
When you press the link set to the string "Stackdriver Provisioning Service", it will be displayed as follows.

> About this service
>   Stackdriver Provisioning Service is used to provision a project for monitoring by Stackdriver. Enabling this service will enable Monitoring API, Logging API and Resource Metadata API.

Comment: Welcome to [so].Please check [ask] and [topics that can be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What does the question mark say next to private?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation. It looks like the `stackdriverprovisioning.googleapis.com` service is enabled automatically when a GCP project is added to a Stackdriver Account. I was able to get this service re-enabled (after accidentally disabling it) by [removing](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/accounts/guide#remove-project) the GCP project from the Stackdriver account and then adding the GCP project back.